# iPhone Hyperlinks

Tags: iphone

Hello
    I am new to iDevice development.I am able to show a html page in iPhone.but if i give a  hyperlink , the hyperlinks is not working.how to give html hyperlinks in iPhone

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "giving hyperlinks"?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Interface Builder, click on your UIWebView and in the Attributes Inspector palette, in the Web View section, turn on the checkbox for Links.

If you've created the UIWebView in code (or if you'd prefer to do it this way) you can turn on Links like this:

```
yourWebViewName.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```